# Terminal short cut to toggle scroll on output

Tags: command-line, shortcut-keys

When developing I faced the situation, where I want to quickly enable / disable the "scroll on output" setting from the Terminal.

Does such a shortcut exist (while being in the Terminal context) or is it possible to "record" a shortcut for such a toggle action?

Comment: Do you mean pressing Ctrl+s to freeze scrolling, and Ctrl+q to resume?  or pipe commands to `more`?

Comment: Freeze / resume is what I looked for. Where did you find documentation about these commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to just freeze / resume the output of the terminal, just use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> to **Stop** output and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Q</kbd> to **Quit stopping** the output...

It's basic [bash](https://ss64.com/bash/syntax-keyboard.html) keyboard handling...

#### :-)

Comment: Thank you, I did not thought of looking at external resources but makes sense since bash is used beyond Ubuntu.

Comment: YW. Favour returned: Question upvoted.  Us oldsters take a lot for granted. Have a loot at Shift+PgUp and Shift+PgDn as well...   **:-)**